# Can floating group headers used in iOS be used on the desktop?

Tags: cocoa, ios, nsoutlineview

In iOS list view group headers stick to the top of the view until pushed off-screen by the next group header when the user scrolls. This doesn't seem to be a standard behavior in Cocoa of OS X. Is it possible to use this behavior on an outline view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! The guy behind Noodlesoft wrote a nice category to do so. Take a look at [Sticky Section Headers](http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2009/09/25/sticky-section-headers-in-nstableview/).

Comment: +1 this works pretty well, but I had some trouble getting it do exactly what I needed when I tried them.  However, it's worth a shot! :)

Comment: we have a functional header row, action buttons and the ability to collapse a group so it won't be as straightforward, but hopefully this will get us on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

In Lion and later, you can use `NSTableView`'s `setFloatsGroupRows`.

```
[myTableView setFloatsGroupRows:YES];
```

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setFloatsGroupRows%3a).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it's not available as a standard behavior. You need to write the code yourself.

However, I recommend strongly *against* using that behavior. It's standard on iOS, so it perfectly matches the environment. But it's not standard on Macs, and it will look strange on it. Don't port the behavior of iOS just because you want to port it; stick to the standard interface behavior of OS X unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: The reasoning behind it is the same as why it is used in iOS, when in a long list the users can lose the concept of where they are (parent group) with the floating group headers you alleviate this problem.

Comment: Call me old fashioned but `NSBrowser` would be better fit on this purpose on OS X. I mean, the screen size of OS X is far larger than that of iOS, so you shouldn't just put everything on a single vertical list. You should better use the horizontal direction available. In general I don't like iOS UI objects used in OS X. Well Apple itself is doing it, so maybe there's no point in complaining about it. anyway ...

Comment: Thanks for the input Yuji, in this particular implementation there are tight horizontal limitations but almost none in the vertical direction, while i agree with you in principal, this is the ideal layout for our users in this particular use case.